# this-command-key-vector and representation of Return key?

Tags: elisp, key-bindings

**Q:** how do I get `this-command-key-vector` to return a character vector when called with the return key?

Consider the following simple command, which will echo the vector of keys that invoked it:

```
(defun test-echo ()
  (interactive)
  (message "%s" (this-command-keys-vector)))
```

Now let's bind it to two keys:

```
(local-set-key "i" #'test-echo)
(local-set-key [return] #'test-echo)
```

When typing <kbd>i</kbd>, the function correctly messages me with the vector `[105]`, which corresponds to *i*'s character representation `(eq ?i 105)`.  However, when typing <kbd>return</kbd>, it echoes `[return]`, when I would have expected `[10]`, i.e., `?\n`.

First of all, is this a problem with my understanding of `this-command-key-vector`, my understanding of `return`, or both?  Second of all, how do I get `this-command-key-vector` to return a character (ie, the integer value) rather than the symbol `return` (or, alternately, how do I translate `return` to a character)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with your understanding of `return`.

`<return>` is a pseudo-function key. It is not the same thing as `RET`, which corresponds to `C-m` (decimal `13`).  Depending on your keyboard, when you hit the `Enter` or `Return` key, Emacs might receive one or the other. Use `C-h k` followed by hitting that key, to see what Emacs tells you it receives.  For example, when I do that I see this:

```
RET (translated from <return>) runs the command...
```

`[return]` is the vector representation of the pseudo-function key `<return>`.

Comment: Interesting!  Would it therefore be accurate to say that it's not sensible to translate `[return]` to a character integer in the same way that it's not sensible for, say, `[f10]`?

Comment: @Dan: Absolutely. At least that's my understanding. (I'm no expert on this.)